# jQuery Mobile: filtering nested lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to be able to implement a filter in my jQuery Mobile project that would allow me to search a nested list and return all list elements that match the text entered into the filter bar. Basically I need to extend the functionality of the already implemented data-filter function to show results from nested list items as well as visible ones. Is there a way to modify the data-filter behaviour?

My list is set up as follows. I need to return a list with each sitesource and datasource (including child elements) that match the search term.

```
<ul>
<li class="sitesource">
    <ul>
        <li class="datasource"></li>
        <li class="datasource"></li>
        <li class="datasource"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="sitesource">
    <ul>
        <li class="sitesource">
            <ul>
                <li class="datasource"></li>
                <li class="datasource"></li>
                <li class="datasource"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="datasource"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="datasource"></li>
</ul>
```

I suspect that what I may need to do is (after pageinit) search through the entire html document and return all the matching sitesource and datasource elements in a list - this would probably require a custom built function?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I've fiddled with http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/ - however I'm in the planning stage of my current sprint and I want to make sure the method I'm working on will actually do as I intend before I commit time to coding (I've already been bitten once, spending hours on a feature that would never work as I intended and wasting valuable time)

Comment: I also want to see if anyone else has successfully modified the existing data-filter, because if I write a custom function I'll have to schedule more time to ensure its styled correctly etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little verbose, but seems to do what you're asking:

```
function filterSources(myVal){
var myFilter = myVal;

var dataSources = document.getElementsByClassName("datasource");

//array from nodelist    
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0, n; n = dataSources[i]; ++i) arr.push(n);

//filter for text    
var finalData = arr.filter(function(element){
        return $(element).text().indexOf(myFilter) > -1;
    })
//compile into string for output
var newStr = "";
for(var m in finalData) newStr += finalData[m].textContent + ", ";
$("#target").html(newStr);


}

$(function(){

filterSources
$("input#search_foo").keyup(function(){
    filterSources($(this).val())
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/klatzkaj/DEmWE/9/

Comment: I can't verify this right now, but it looks very much like the solution I eventually implemented (though mine was far messier). Unfortunately I no longer have access to the code I wrote due to contractual restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is so old,
but right now i meet the same problem and has found the solution

Fortunately with the latest JQM (1.4.5) you can easily add `data-children=".datasource"` on the parent `<ul>` attribute

For more info : http://api.jquerymobile.com/filterable/#option-children

Hope my answer can help anyone else who meet the same problem,
regards